# What is the difference between date handling in my queries?

Tags: sql-server

I need the number of records of last month. I used to use this approach so far:

```
select 
 count(ID)
from 
 table
where
 col1 = 'somerule'
and 
 DateTimeOfInsert >= '20150901' 
and 
 DateTimeOfInsert <= '20150930'
```

Now I'm about to atomate this task and therefore I have to pull the start and end dates of last month automatically. So here it is:

```
select 
 count(ID)
from 
 table
where
 col1 = 'somerule'
and 
 DATEPART(m, DateTimeOfInsert) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
and 
 DATEPART(yyyy, DateTimeOfInsert) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

My only issue is that at this very moment the first query returns `1073` and the second one `1124`. So the question is obvious: what is the difference between them? Both should inlude the start and end date. I can't spot it.

Comment: Some good reading on this - [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries), and also [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition:

```
DateTimeOfInsert >= '20150901' and  DateTimeOfInsert <= '20150930'
```

retrieves record that are between `2015-09-01 00:00:00.000` and `2015-09-30 00:00:00.000`.

If `DateTimeOfInsert` is `DATETIME`, then this will return different result from your other condition.

The best way for this kind of queries is not to use `BETWEEN` but rather use 
`>= and <`. In your case, you want to get records for the last month, so you want to use `>= start of last month` and `< start of this month`:

```
DateTimeOfInsert >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)    -- Beginning of previous month
AND DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)  -- Beginning of this month
```

The above condition also makes your query sargable.

For some common date routines, see this [**article.**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/lynnpettis/2009/03/25/some-common-date-routines/)

Comment: Thank you for this. In this case my only question is: why is the 2nd approach in my original Q is not good enough?

Comment: Because it's not sargable. You should not use functions on your columns in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @fishmong3r, if you are applying functions / some calculations on columns in predicate like datediff(...), cast(...), col + '.' etc, then it becomes not sargable that meant that no index that is created on that column will be used.

Comment: With your approach I get these records too: `10/1/2015 12:04 PM`.

Comment: @fishmong3r, Sorry. it should be `DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)` for the beginning of this month.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in `time` component of `datetime`.

This:

```
DateTimeOfInsert >= '20150901' and DateTimeOfInsert <= '20150930'
```

will not select date like `20150930 15:30`.

But this:

```
DATEPART(m, DateTimeOfInsert) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
```

will select it because you are checking for months and year part only. That`s why the second select returns more rows.

Both queries will return the same if you just change the first statement so that it will consider time component of last day of month:

```
DateTimeOfInsert >= '20150901' and DateTimeOfInsert < '20151001'
```

Comment: Honestly I doubt that as if I use `*` instead of `count(ID)` I get a lot of precise time entries like `9/2/2015 11:17 AM` or `9/4/2015 11:49 AM`. In fact all the `DateTimeOfInsert' records have the time component.

Comment: Can't get what you are talking about. The fact that  `DateTimeOfInsert` records have the time component makes difference for your statements and I have explained why...

Comment: @fishmong3r, yes you'll get records with time component. But notice that there are no records exceeding `'2015-09-30 00:00:00.000'`.